# How to use forms.HtmlField for in Django forms.Form

Tags: django, django-forms

I  am building an api to [send mail](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/email/#send-mail).
In the view i want to validate the post data using django form.

Here is my query:

***How to use `forms.HtmlField` for in Django `forms.Form`***

I want to change my `html_message` from `CharField` to `HtmlField`

```
class SendMailForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField()
    message = forms.TextField()
    recipient = forms.EmailField()
    html_message = forms.CharField()
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [**Built-in Widgets**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/widgets/#built-in-widgets) on Django Docs.

There is no such HtmlField, but shows you how to use the existing widgets and create your own.

I would go with:

```
message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())
```